# HTML code on K2 platform that helps to manipulate clickable images

Tags: k2

As I add affiliate links from Amazon on my articles (two ads of books from Amazon right now posted at the bottom of the article, http://www.sdsolutions.firm.in/life-insurance/item/16-relevance-of-direct-marketing-for-life-insurance-agents-in-rural-india), I do not have the flexibility to manipulate images like dragging to the right, left, center or placing a number of images (or clickable ads) side-by-side. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

A good WYSIWYG editor for Joomla (like JCE) will assist you in performing such tasks. Alternatively, you can create K2 Extra Fields and place them where you want your ads to be. This will provide more "granular" control over what gets output but the caveat is that you cannot move these placements/positions by drag'n'drop once coded into your item.php template override. Obviously :)